# Fact table primary key

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a fact table with 8 foreign keys (referencing 8 dimensions), but even a combination of all eight keys does not uniquely identify a row. Do I need to add another attribute from the original data (i.e. "project-id" attribute, which is useless for anything), so that I can have a primary key, or I can leave fact table as it is, without a primary key?

Comment: Give us more information. What are the keys and what is the reality behind? There are maybe some design patterns applicable to your situation already.

Comment: @twn08 This is actually a homework assignment. I was given data in this **[csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7u1nrh33yx26i8c/data.csv)** and my task is to make a star schema. I don't have any other info about the data, so I need to figure out dimension and fact tables myself.

Comment: Well, you can't really create dimensional model without understanding your data. I can see that these are some projects in some countries over time. Maybe you can list attributes in that file, their meaning and possible values and your current solution. There has to be some primary key in every table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first rule of a fact table is to **[declare your grain](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2001/03/design-tip-21-declaring-the-grain/)** - what uniquely identifies a row.

It sounds like you haven't declared your grain for this table. If the grain of the table is "one row per project", then you need to include project as a degenerate dimension in the table.

Comment: this is the best answer. have duplicate pk is not a problem like we can have it in scd 2 or in case of full data refresh from source , but you have to define the grain , for your problem you can include source surrogate key as part of pk but beware  this will create problem for downstream to identify the row ( unless you have dates and use qualify to use only one row from 2 ). I will suggest you to recheck the design or you can create a big mess of data.

Answer (score 1):

Every table must have a primary key.  That's relational rule #1.

You can always add a surrogate key, but I like the idea of a fact table having attributes that satisfy a unique constraint.  I second your idea: add more attributes until you have a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Along with those 8 foreign key include a simple surrogate key (like a row  index) to each row. This will identify every row of the fact table uniquely

For a surrogate key you may start from an index say 1 for the first row and then increment the index by one each time you make a new entry to  the fact table